# WinSCP .NET assembly with VBA throwing ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: .net, excel, vba, winscp, winscp-net

I have recently registered the `WinSCPnet.dll` using .NET Framework `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727`. And I have added the tlb file generated to my VBA references. But when I try to instantiate `SessionOptions` object, it throws an error *"ActiveX component can't create object"*. Not sure what went wrong here.

Also, I found that I was able to connect using VBScript. But if I use VBA, it is not working. Can anyone suggest what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If your Microsoft Excel installation is 32-bit application, you have to register the `WinSCPnet.dll` for 32-bit .NET framework, even on a 64-bit system.

As the instructions for [registering the WinSCP .NET assembly for COM](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#registering) show, on 64-bit system, you generally need to register the assembly both for 32-bit and 64-bit:

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe WinSCPnet.dll /codebase /tlb:WinSCPnet32.tlb
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe WinSCPnet.dll /codebase /tlb:WinSCPnet64.tlb
```

Do not add the `.tbl` manually to Excel. The assembly appears itself after being registered correctly.